# Show that a set of functions is dense in $L^2(0,2)$

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, analysis

Show that a set of functions 
$$A=\{f\in C^0([0,2]):\ f(0)=f(1)=f(2)=0\}$$
is dense in $L^2(0,2)$.

I know the following theorem: Let $1\le p<\infty$, $\ \Omega\ $ be an open set of $\mathbb{R}^n$. Then continuous functions with compact support are dense in $L^p(\Omega)$.

In my case the functions are defined on $[0,2]$ that is closed. The definition of support is
$$supp\ f:=\overline{\{x\in X : f(x)\ne 0\}}$$
that is a closed set.

Now for a function in $A$ I can write the support like this (tell me any mistakes)
$$supp\ f=\overline{(0,1)\cup (1,2)}$$
that I think it's equal to $[0,2]$. Can I apply the previous theorem being my domain closed? Or maybe there is a different way to solve this?

Comment: $supp(f)=\overline{(0,1)\cup (1,2)}$ doesn’t make sense as the RHS doesn’t depend on $f$.

Comment: For $f$ in $A$ you always have $\mathrm{supp } f \subset [0, 2] = \overline{(0, 1) \cup (1, 2)}$. However, not all continuous functions with compact support are elements of $A$, consider for example the constant function $1$.

Comment: $\overline{(0,1)\cup (1,2)}=[0,2]$, and the supports of functions in $A$ are never this set.

Comment: So I can't apply that theorem or what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's enough to show $A$ is dense in $C[0,2]$ in the $L^2$ metric. So let $f\in C[0,2],$ with $M=\max_{[0,2]}|f|.$ For $n=1,2,\dots,$ set

$$f_n(x) = f(x)d(x,\{0,1,2\})^{1/n}.$$

Then each $f_n \in A.$ Furthermore $f_n \to f$ pointwise on $[0,2]\setminus \{0,1,2\}.$ We want to show

$$\tag 1\int_0^2 |f_n-f|^2\to 0.$$

But this is easy: First, we know $f_n\to f$ a.e. on $[0,2].$ Second, $|f_n|\le M$ for all $n.$ Hence the integrands in $(1)$ are bounded above by $4M^2.$ By the dominated convergence theorem, $(1)$ holds as desired.

Comment: Cuold you explain me why you take $f_n(x)=f(x)d(x,\{0,1,2\})^{1/n}$. I think  $f_n$ converges poitwise to $f(x)$ because $\lim_{n\to\infty}f_n=f(x)d(x,\{0,1,2\})^0=f(x)$. Right?

Comment: Cuold you explain why $(1)$ is bounded by $4M^2$?

Comment: I think this is an easier solution than the previous one but I miss some calculation steps.

Comment: For some reason your comments were not showing up in my in box until now. First question: Yes, if $a>0,$ then $a^{1/n} \to 1.$ For the second question: Do you see that each $|f_n|\le |f|\le M?$

Comment: $|f|\le M$ is obvious, $|f_n|\le M$ because $d(x,\{0,1,2\})\le 1/2$, we get $f_n(x)\le \frac{1}{2}f(x)$, but I miss the last step to get $4M^2$.

Comment: @GiacomoTabarelli $\, |f_n-f| \le |f_n|+|f| \le M+M = 2M.$

Comment: If I have $f(0)=f(1)=f(2)=1$ how I can set $f_n(x)$? Cause I tried some ways like $f_n(x)=2f(x)d(x,\{0,1,2\})^{1/n}$ and $f_n(x)=(f(x)-1)d(x,\{0,1,2\})^{1/n}$ but they don't converge pointwise to $f(x)\in C^0([0,2])$. Then I thought $f_n(x)=f(x)d(x,\{0,2\})^{1/n}$ and it seems to be convergent poinwise to $f(x)$ but $f_n(0)=f_n(2)=0$, so I thought $f_n(x)=f(x)(d(x,\{0,1,2\})+1)^{1/n}$, is this the right way?

Comment: @GiacomoTabarelli Try $f_n(x) = f(x)(1-d(x,\{0,1,2\})^{1/n}.$

Comment: First I thought that $f_n(x)=f(x)(d(x,\{0,1,2\})+1)^{1/n}$ wasn't bounded above, then I realize $|f_n(x)|\le 3/2f(x)$, but to apply the dominated convergence theorem must I have $f_n(x)\le f(x)$? A dominated convergenge theorem's hyphothesis is $|f_n|\le g(x)$, so could $f_n\to f$ from above or it must converge to $f$ from below? Cause with my $f_n$ it seems converge to $f$ from above. Or maybe I make some mistake.

Comment: @GiacomoTabarelli $|f_n| \le 3/2 |f|$ is just fine with DCT.

Comment: Ok so I can use any function I can build as long as $f_n\to f$ pointwise and $|f_n|\le g(x)$. Is there any reason to choose your $f_n$ respect to mine?

Comment: @GiacomoTabarelli Your choice is actually better I think; less tricky.

Comment: Ok thanks a lot, you were very helpful!

Comment: @zhw. Thank you for the answer. Could you explain more about the sentence "It's enough to show $A$ is dense in $C[0,2]$ in the $L^2$ metric" ? Is it because $C^0$ is dense in $L^p$ ?

Comment: @soundwave Yes, I was using that result.

Comment: @zhw. Thank you. Moreover, could you explain why the sequence $f_n(x) = f(x)d(x,\{0,1,2\})^{1/n}$ you definied belongs to $A$? Aren't the points $0,1$ and $2$ removable discontinuities for $f_n$? In this case $f_n$ would be not continuous on $[0,2]$, ie $f_n\notin C^0([0,2])$ and so $f_n\notin A$. But maybe I'm wrong.

Comment: @soundwave $d(x,\{0,1,2\})$ is continuous and equals $0$ at $0,1,2.$

Comment: @zhw. Oh yes sorry my mistake, thank you very much. I'm studying now the case where $A$ is characterized by $f(0)=f(1)=f(2)=1$, I read that you proposed the sequence $f_n(x) = f(x)(1-d(x,\{0,1,2\})^{1/n}$. But $f_n(0)=f(0)\cdot1\ne1$ since $f\notin A$, right? So we could try with $f_n(x) = f(x)(1/f(x)^n-d(x,\{0,1,2\})^{1/n}$ but we should impose $f\ne0$ and maybe we lost the generality of the proof.

Comment: @soundwave You're right, I restudied this exercise and I found your same issue. I thought a lot on it but I didn't find any solution. It seems we can't define a sequence of functions with the distance (in a similar way as before).

Answer (score 4):

Consider

$$B=\{f\in C^0((0,2)):\ f(1)=0 \text{ and } \lim\limits_{x \to 0^+} f(x) = \lim\limits_{x \to 2^-} f(x) =0\}.$$

You have to prove that $B$ is dense in $L^2((0,2))$.

For that, it is sufficient to prove that any continuous function $g$ with compact support included in $(0,2)$ is the limit in $L^2((0,2))$ of $g \cdot f_n$, where $f_n \in B$ is defined by

$$f_n(x)=
\begin{cases}
nx & 0 < x \le 1/n\\
1 & 1/n \le x \le 1-1/n\\
n(1-x) & 1-1/n \le x \le 1\\
n(x-1) & 1\le x \le 1+1/n\\
1 & 1+1/n \le x \le 2-1/n\\
n(2-x)& 2-1/n \le x <2
\end{cases}$$ for $n \ge 3$.

*Drawing the graph of $f_n$ will help you to understand the background idea!*

This is also using the fact that for $\mathcal F \subseteq \mathcal G \subseteq H$, if $\mathcal F$ is dense in $\mathcal G$ and $\mathcal G$ is dense in $\mathcal H$, then $\mathcal F$ is dense in $\mathcal H$.

Comment: Nice construction !

Comment: I understand your $f_n$, but can't understand the density here

Comment: See the last sentence of my response and prove that $\lim\limits_{ n \to \infty} \int \vert g -g\cdot f_n\vert^2 =0$.

Comment: Ok, now I can see the set is dense. It's a bit hard for me to understand these new things. Thanks